# Could we use Travis CI for Gitorious?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, gitorious

Travis CI is a good continuous integration tool for Github. Could we use Travis CI for Gitorious?

Is there any good continuous integration tool for Gitorious? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but travis-ci only supports GitHub right now, unless you want to set up your gitorious repo to mirror to GitHub like [this](https://exyr.org/2011/git-mirrors/)